# Showing that linear transformation $T$ with $T^3+T=0$ and $T\neq0$ is not an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have the linear transformation $T:V\to V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ where $\dim V=3$, with $T^3+T=0$ and $T\neq0$. I want to prove that $T$ is not an isomorphism, and I don't want to use eigenvalues.

I tried to assume that it is an isomorphism and I got to $T^2=-I$,
and I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: why don't you want to use eigenvalues ? using the kernel is fundamental in linear algebra, especially when talking about isomorphisms.

Comment: they want us to think of another way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer before the edit concerning the dimension :**

The result is not true, take $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $$T(x,y)=(y,-x)$$

as a counterexample.

**Answer after the edit concerning the dimension :**

It is true, though, with the additionnal assumption that $\dim(V)$ is finite and odd : indeed, in that case, let's assume that $T$ is an isomorphism with $T^3+T=0$. Then $T^2=-\mathrm{Id}_V$, so $\det(T)^2 = (-1)^{\dim(V)}=-1$, which is impossible since $\det(T) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right didn't thought of that approach, thank you